# A guide to hyphenation in economics?

Tags: definition

In the econ literature, what is the convention when it comes to (not) hypenating some common terms like:

- first(-?)best, second(-?)best,...
- best(-?)response?
- ...

The Economist suggests that ["There is no firm rule to help you decide which words are run together, hyphenated or left separate"](http://www.economist.com/style-guide/hyphens) so I thought people here could be more aware of the conventions in econ than people, say, at http://english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Personally for compound adjectives I would use "This response is second best" but "This is a second-best response".  So long as you are not ambiguous, I doubt it matters.

Comment: Of all the responses to this question, I like the second best.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about economics. It's about typographic conventions.

Comment: My advice would be to get a good style guide, such as the Chicago manual and follow its advice.

Answer (score 5):

Plamen Nikolov of Binghamton University presents a brief treatment of this in "Writing Tips For Economics Research Papers". He notes that there are two basic rules of economic usage:

> "Long run" (without a hyphen) is a noun. "Long-run" (with a hyphen) is
>   an adjective. Same with short(-)run. and "Saving" (without a terminal
>   s) is a flow. "Savings" (with a terminal s) is a stock.